# Adding a battery to a display board

Tags: power-supply, batteries, pcb, power-electronics

This needs to be portable. I have a display PCB board for a monitor. I want to add a battery, in a safe low risk way and no soldering. It currently takes in a 12 V power supply. I attached an image of the power section of the board. What are some ways I can go about doing this?

[image: Corner of PCB Board]

Comment: Safe, low risk, no soldering? Buy a UPS. =-D

Comment: It's unlikely you can do this with no soldering at all; I would use a 12 volt lead-acid battery connected to a voltage regulator of some sort, because I don't know if the monitor can handle the voltage variation of an unregulated battery.

Comment: @Tyler it needs to be portable. Thanks for taking the time to read and comment!

Comment: @Hearth is it safe to do with no experience and YouTube my way through it?

Comment: You didn't say in your post that it needed to be portable...

Comment: Why don't you just feed the 12V battery in via the DC connector? If you buy the cable you don't even need to solder. Be warned to add a fuse and as close to battery terminal as possible. If you don't have a fuse and the wires get shorted, the battery can deliver enough current to heat the plastic insulation and wires can glow red hot which can ignite fire and be also hard to cut power by hand.

Comment: Depends what you call safe. Soldering involves temperatures more than hot enough to give you pretty bad burns, if you use the equipment extremely incorrectly. A car battery, if you're using one of those, can provide enough current to severely injure you if you aren't careful. Nothing is ever 100% safe, but I think it's unlikely you'd injure yourself any worse than maybe a minor burn if you do a little research about what you're doing.

Comment: @Justme are you referring to two solutions? If I get a 12v battery like this https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/power-supplies/12v-dc-battery-power-supply-8-cell-aa-battery-holder/934/ why would I need to add fuses and worry about shorting?

Comment: It depends. You did not say which batteries. I was maybe referring to car or bike batteries. If you were referring to standard alkaline or rechargeable, you should have mentioned what batteries you mean. And you don't seem to care about safety if you don't want fuses, as you may not be aware the safety risks of batteries with a lot of energy. But do you even have clue if batteries can give enough current to your system? And if yes, for how long? Have you done any math what your requirements are and how to achieve those requirements.

Comment: @Justme I am new to this, therefore you are correct, I have done no math as I am unsure what math to do. It is a portable lcd monitor extracted from an old laptop and this is the display controller I am powering which also powers the lcd. For fuses, I have no clue why they are even needed, what they are, how to put one on, etc. I appreciate the time you are spending with my question.

Comment: First define how much current the thing takes. Your batteries and wires need to deliver it. Then define how long you want to run the display. That defines hiw much battery capacity you need. That defines how many kilograms of batteries you need. If you randomly give it AA alkalines, they may not provide enough current and even if they do you might end up with 10 minutes of use with them. Know the numbers.

Comment: @Justme It needs 5amps (rough estimate, based on the average screen 50watts as I don't know about the exact model). The display board takes .3watts. How do I determine the capacity needed?

Comment: @Justme I also want to try running it off solar if I am successful with a simple battery. I want 7-10 hours of capacity

Comment: @JacobMiller 7-10 hours at 50 watts is quite a lot of energy, you may want to look at car batteries for that kind of capacity. AAs will absolutely not cut it, not unless you want to have several hundred of them in series-parallel strings. Have you looked to see if there are any commercial devices (sold for e.g. campers or something) that do what you want already?

Comment: As I suspected, AA batteries simply can't provide the 4+ amps needed, and for providing 5A for 10 hours you need a 50 Ah battery, i.e. a heavy car battery.

Comment: You could probably reduce the input voltage some. Looks like it has both a linear and switching regulation circuit on there. This will reduce your total power needs but the current required will still be high.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly you'd define portable, but one of these car jump starter units may suit you.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/RAC-Jump-Starter-Rechargeable-Orange/dp/B00FB7LTO8

This particular model has a fused 12 Volt 10 Amp output already built into it. It runs off a 10 amp hour internal lead acid battery, so may not provide power for as long as you've said you want. But if you look around you may find another model that does provide the battery life you're looking for. Or you may decide that this is an acceptable compromise.

Using something like this is a safe and simple ready made solution. You'd just need to source or make a cable to connect from the DC output connector of the power supply to the DC input connector of the board you are powering.